# which is the most efficient way to save power with battery using Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, battery, temperature-sensor

I am working with a ArduinoUNO - 2100 mA battery, and a solar Charger shield. I use a temperature reader that sends info **every half hour with GPS-GSM shield** called LONET (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/LoNet_-_GSM/GPRS/GPS_Breakout for more info).

I want to save all the energy i can, i am trying to put Arduino UNO and LONET on Sleep mode.

LONE has its own mode via “AT+CSCLK=1”.

But for Arduino UNO i haven seen a library called Narcoleptic (https://code.google.com/p/narcoleptic/ for more info) wich can solve the problem.

My question is:

Is there any other method that can help me to save Battery with Arduino uno? is it a good approach to use Narcoleptic or there is another method to do it?

Thanks for your time/help and sorry for my English.

Any feedback could be welcome.

Comment: The uno board isn't very power efficient. There is the USB-to-serial chip that doesn't sleep. And the voltage regulator (I've heard) isn't very efficient. Sleeping the ATMega doesn't really help a lot. Better go with something like a Arduino Mini, and use an external programmer.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, i will try to search info about Arduino Mini.

Comment: The regulator is horribly inefficient, especially when paired with the power steering circuitry in the Uno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an even greater article on this topic: http://www.gammon.com.au/power

It shows how to reduce your power usage for the Uno from about 50mA to 350nA (0.000350mA) - at this point, you need to factor in the natural drain of batteries.

Also, I have had good success with a project that was activated by a pushbutton, by using a latch - the push button turned the power on; once the power is on, it latched. Then the Arduino can switch itself off, using one of it's pins. As far as I can tell from a simulator, there is no leakage (while it is off, to within the accuracy of the simulator, assuming a perfectly spherical transistor in a vacuum ;) ).

Just in case anyone is interested, my latch circuit can be seen at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf9sX.png - the two resistors and the switch at the bottom represent the Arduino - +5V coming in the top, GND at the bottom, and one of the pin to switch it off is the switch - this pin should be INPUT to keep the power on; when you are ready to switch of, set it to output -> high. You should get switched off immediately. The switch at the top will switch it on. In the startup part of your sketch, set the pin to INPUT first.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great article on that topic: https://www.openhomeautomation.net/arduino-battery/